# C call --wrapped function indirectly

Tags: c, cmake

I've wrapped a function `argp_usage()` using CMake's `set_target_properties` like so:

[project_root/test/CMakeLists.txt]

```
add_executable(test_args test_args.c)
target_link_libraries(test_args cmocka)
add_test(NAME test_args COMMAND test_args)
set_target_properties(test_args PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--wrap=argp_usage")
```

However, my production code still calls the real `argp_usage()`.

The problem is that my test code does not actually call argp_usage directly, rather it calls out to my production code which then calls argp_usage, like so:

[project_root/test/test_args.c]

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <cmocka.h>
#include "../src/args.c"
#include "../src/args.h"

void __wrap_argp_usage(struct argp_state *state)
{
    assert_non_null(state);
}

void parseArgs_inputIsValid_return0(void **state)
{
    int rv, argc = 2;
    char *argv[argc];
    argv[0] = "eternity";
    argv[1] = "--help";

    rv = parse_args(argc, argv);

    assert_int_equal(rv, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    const struct CMUnitTest tests[] =
    {
        cmocka_unit_test(parseArgs_inputIsValid_return0),
    };

    return cmocka_run_group_tests(tests, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Notice the call `rv = parse_args(argc, argv);`, that is the call out to my production code and the function is defined like so:

[project_root/src/args.c]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <config.h>
#include "args.h"

/* argp requires these to be global */
const char *argp_program_version = PACKAGE_VERSION;
const char *argp_program_bug_address = PACKAGE_BUGREPORT;

error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
    struct args *args = state->input;

    if (args->count > 128)
        argp_usage(state);

    switch (key)
    {
        case 'q': case 's':
            args->silent = 1;
            break;

        case 'v':
            args->verbose = 1;
            break;

        case 'o':
            args->output_file = arg;
            break;

        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            if (args->count-- < 0)
                break;
            break;

        case ARGP_KEY_END:
            if (state->arg_num < 1)
                argp_usage(state);
            break;

        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int parse_args(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rv;
    const char* doc = "Eternity - your window to the good";
    char args_doc[] = "file1.jpg file2.png file3.bmp ...";

    struct argp_option options[] = {
        {"verbose",'v', 0, 0, "Produce verbose output", 0},
        {"quiet",  'q', 0, 0, "Don't produce any output", 0},
        {"silent", 's', 0, OPTION_ALIAS, NULL, 0},
        {"output", 'o', "FILE", 0, "Output to FILE instead of std output", 0},
        {0}
    };

    struct argp argp = {options, parse_opt, args_doc, doc, NULL, 0, NULL};
    struct args args;
    args.count = argc;
    args.silent = args.verbose = 0;
    args.output_file = "-";

    rv = argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &args);

    if (rv != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, strerror(rv));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, finally, the one that actually calls `argp_usage()` (the function I'm trying to wrap) is this `parse_opt()` function, which is a callback used by the argp library but defined by me the user.

How can I wrap `argp_usage()` so that if it gets called indirectly like this it will still call the wrapper function `__wrap_argp_usage()`?

Comment: If you run a [verbose build](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F) do you see the linker option being passed as expected?

Comment: Yes. The wrapper even works when I call argp_usage from my test code, but not from my production code.

Comment: I think your production code (unlike debug) wants to inline the function. Have a look at the assembly I'd say.

Comment: Why are "including" the C source, i.e. `arg.c`? This should be a separate library.